# Remove the blank space in vi editor created by "set nu" option

Tags: 14.04, vim

I have used vi editor several times on many different machines, but I have never seen such an behavior of `set nu` option.

This is what my vi editor looks after I set the `set nu` option in `.vimrc` file in my home directory:
[image: vi editor screen-shot]

As clearly seen, some amount of whitespace is being created to the left of line numbers. How can I remove this space so that I can better make use of my workspace.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running it as `vi` or `vim`? Did you test after adding `nocompatible`?  The [docs](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27numberwidth%27) say: `'numberwidth' is reset to 8 when 'compatible' is set.`

Comment: @muru I am running it as `vi`. Yes, I have tested it after adding `set nocompatible` option, as already shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Run it as `vim`. No, your screenshot doesn't tell me that - for all I know you could have added it, and then taken the screenshot.

Comment: @muru Yeah! As this is a new installation of Ubuntu, when I tried to open with `vim`, I realized that `vim` is not installed, so after installation of vim it works, with both `vi` as well as `vim`. But, what was the editor which got opened when I tried to previously open with `vi` ?

Comment: its `vim.tiny` a barebones version of Vim: http://askubuntu.com/a/434632/158442'

Comment: @muru thanks for pointing that out. I hope this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help on `nu` ([`:h 'number'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27number%27))

```
                                'number' 'nu' 'nonumber' 'nonu'
'number' 'nu'           boolean (default off)
                            local to window
        Print the line number in front of each line.  When the 'n' option is
        excluded from 'cpoptions' a wrapped line will not use the column of
        line numbers (this is the default when 'compatible' isn't set).
        The 'numberwidth' option can be used to set the room used for the line
        number.
```

And in turn, from `:h 'numberwidth'`:

```
'numberwidth' 'nuw'     number  (Vim default: 4  Vi default: 8)
                        local to window
                        {not in Vi}
                        {only available when compiled with the +linebreak
                        feature}
        Minimal number of columns to use for the line number.  Only relevant
        when the 'number' or 'relativenumber' option is set or printing lines
        with a line number. Since one space is always between the number and
        the text, there is one less character for the number itself.
        The value is the minimum width.  A bigger width is used when needed to
        fit the highest line number in the buffer respectively the number of
        rows in the window, depending on whether 'number' or 'relativenumber'
        is set. Thus with the Vim default of 4 there is room for a line number
        up to 999. When the buffer has 1000 lines five columns will be used.
        The minimum value is 1, the maximum value is 10.
        NOTE: 'numberwidth' is reset to 8 when 'compatible' is set.
```

That is, the default width is 4, but 8 when in `compatible` mode. [`vi` in default Ubuntu is `vim.tiny`](https://askubuntu.com/a/434632/158442), which doesn't support `nocompatible`, so the width became `8`. You need to install `vim` to get the normal behaviour.

That said, if you do wish to set a different minimum width, say 2, just do:

```
set nuw=2
```